# First characters being lost when reading from InputStream

Tags: java, stream

I have the following code:

```
public class Interface {

    public void exec(){
        try {
            _inputStream.read();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( _inputStream ));
            System.out.println( br.readLine() );
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }

    }

    public void setInputStream( InputStream inputStream ){
        _inputStream = inputStream;
    }

    private InputStream _inputStream;

}

public class Run {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Interface ui = new Interface();
        ui.setInputStream( new ByteArrayInputStream( "2 4 N".getBytes( Charset.defaultCharset() ) ) );
        ui.exec();
    }
}
```

Whenever I run this code though, all I get printed out is

```
" 4 N"
```

The first character has been lost. What is happening to my stream and what can I do to prevent it?

Comment: You read it in your code: why are you surprised?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
_inputStream.read();
```

consumes one character that doesn't go to the `BufferedReader`.  You discarded that character yourself.  Just delete that line and you should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are calling `_inputStream.read();` first. Just remove that line.